# есть ли способ определить было ли присвоено значение к какому либо полю, даже если это значение определённое по умолчанию

Tags: golang

Есть функция которая принимает структуру с числовым полем, в функции нужно проверить следующее: если в поле было записано значение то вернуть true, а если нет, то false. При этом 0 также может быть присвоенным значением, то есть если присвоить полю 0, то функция должна вернуть true.

```
type Data struct {
    Num int
}

func test(d Data) bool {
    // если d.Num  значение присвоено, даже если это ноль то вернуть true   
    // иначе false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам лучше всего использовать для этого методы-сеттеры. Что касается структуры, вы можете либо использовать указатели, либо доп. булево поле, либо сделать конструктор, который возвращает какое-то особое значение поля. То есть либо:

```golang
type Data struct {
    numSet bool
    num    int
}

func (d *Data) SetNum(n int) { d.numSet, d.num = true, n }
```

Либо:

```golang
type Data struct {
    num *int
}

func (d *Data) SetNum(n int) { d.num = &n }
```

Либо:

```golang
type Data struct {
    num int
}

func NewData() *Data {
    return &Data{
        num: math.MaxInt32,
    }
}
```

Выбор делайте сами, в зависимости от ситуации. Вариант с указателями я лично считаю наименее предпочтительным, так как есть опасность нулевого указателя и доп. нагрузка на сборщик мусора.